# Python Convert IP to octal address

Tags: python, python-2.7, ip, converters, octal

how to convert IP address to dotted octal address in python 2.7 ?
example something like this ': 127.0.0.1 = 0177.0000.0000.0001'

i have try this but give me different result

```
ip = '127.0.0.1'
print '.'.join([oct(int(x)+256)[3:] for x in ip.split('.')])
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

[EDIT: Thanks to abarnert for pointing out a simpler way to use format]

```
>>> ip = '127.0.0.1'
>>> print '.'.join(format(int(x), '04o') for x in ip.split('.'))
0177.0000.0000.0001
```

Comment: You don't need `str.format` when your format string is nothing but a single specifier; just use `format(int(x), '04o')`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
print '%04o.%04o.%04o.%04o' % tuple(map(int, ip.split('.')))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
ip="127.0.0.1"
octalIP='.'.join(["%04o" % int(x) for x in ip.split('.')])
print octalIP
```

output:
   0177.0000.0000.0001